# Constexpr methods for nonconstexpr class

Tags: c++, class, optimization, constexpr

Is there any reason to add constexpr to class's methods if class hasn't any constexpr constructor? Maybe compiler can do some optimizations in this case?

Comment: I share the feeling that this would be useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, one obvious case is when the class is an aggregate class. Aggregate initialization doesn't call any constructor, but can still be used in constant expression evaluation.

Even if the class is not an aggregate class, you can still call a `constexpr` member function in constant expression evaluation if the member function doesn't access any state of the class instance. This is obviously the case for `static` member functions, but can also apply to non-`static` member functions.

For example, the following is valid:

```
struct A {
    int i;        

    // The only usable constructor is the default constructor,
    // which is not `constexpr`.
    // The class is also not an aggregate class because of these declarations.
    A() : i(0) {}
    A(const A&) = delete;

    constexpr int getZero() {
        // return i; would be IFNDR
        return 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    constexpr int x = a.getZero();
}
```

You must be careful though, because if it is completely impossible to call the member function as subexpression of any constant expression, then marking it `constexpr` anyway makes the program *ill-formed, no diagnostic required* (IFNDR). In other words the compiler may refuse to compile such a program.

Also, how often such a situation comes up and the constant evaluation use case is intended (especially for non-`static` member functions), is a different question.

Comment: Is `A` even an aggregate? I know the definition has changed a lot, but afaik every standard has meant that providing your own definition of a default constructor prevents you from being an aggregate. It's both user-declared and user-provided.

Comment: @NathanPierson The code is meant as an example for the "_Even if the class is not aggregate,_" case.

Comment: If the class is an aggregate doesn't it kinda sorta have an constexpr constructor?

Comment: If you have a member function that touches none of the member variables of the class then why not declare it static? Only reason I can think of would be virtual functions where the base or derived functions touch member variables. But then you can't make any of them constexpr, right?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow If you choose the members of the aggregate carefully, then you can make it so that it doesn't have an implicit default constructor, no implicit move constructor and no implicit copy constructor. Then it doesn't have any constructor at all. (Or alternatively you can force them to be non-`constexpr`). The class can then still be aggregate-initialized (in a constant expression), but that doesn't use any of the constructors. Aggregate-initialization doesn't involve any constructor call (on the aggregate itself).

Comment: @user17732522 That's the kinda sorta part. I believe aggregate initialization follows the normal constexpr rules. If all the arguments are constexpr then the result is constexpr.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Since C++20 `virtual` functions can be `constexpr`, but they must be called on an object that is usable in constant expressions or had their lifetime started during evaluation of the constant expression. Therefore it wouldn't be usable without a `constexpr` constructor (or aggregate initialization). I agree that there would seldom be a reason not to make such a function `static`. However, the function is allowed to use members, as long as they are not accessed in the specific constant expression evaluation. E.g. [this](https://godbolt.org/z/GE6Ed8cs4) is allowed.

Comment: @user17732522 But can a virtual function be constexpr in the base class but not in the derived class or vice versa?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow The rules for constant expression evaluation work the other way around. It starts with everything being a constant expression and then gives a list of exceptions which may not be evaluated. Aggregate initialization is not mentioned explicitly in this list. Of course evaluation of the constructors for the members may violate some of the conditions. Calling a non-`constexpr` constructor is included in the general restriction that no non-`constexpr` function may be called (see https://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.3).

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Not completely sure about that, but I think yes. Obviously an actual call at compile-time must be using a `constexpr` final overrider.